# Date will be different when convert from NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

This is My code

```
NSString * dateStr = @"7/25/2013 12:00:00 AM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

NSLog(@"dateStr : %@ , date : %@",dateStr,date);
```

But my Date will be one Day behind the actual date. See this log

```
dateStr : 7/25/2013 12:00:00 AM , date : 2013-07-24 18:30:00 +0000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The missing timezone might be the culprit. What is the timezone of the `dateStr`. I guess it would be GMT+0 and since you are not setting any timeZone to formatter, it would have your local timezone. This might be the reason.

Comment: You have to set time zone

Comment: @Searching But my string does not contain timezone, so if i add `zzz` than wouldn't it will display error?

Comment: Actually both times are same, if you look closely, `dateStr` is in local timeZone and the date log is in UTC, if you add 5.30 to UTC, both would be same :)

Comment: @Anupdas you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSString * dateStr = @"7/25/2013 12:00:00 AM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
 [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

NSLog(@"dateStr : %@ , date : %@",dateStr,date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this . this will help you

```
 NSString * dateStr = @"7/25/2013 12:00:00 AM";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString * dateStr = @"7/25/2013 12:00:00 AM";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    NSLog(@"dateStr : %@ , date : %@",dateStr,date);
```

Setting the time zone fixes this issue